# Grid Layout add Gameobject with Instantiate previous object not from above

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, gameobject

Here I created an `Instantiate function using a click button to create a GameObject from the parent object Layout Grid`, it worked fine

But there's a problem, when i click the button it's initially on top but when i click more than 3 times the `previous GameObject` is on the bottom not on the top and not in order, and that's my problem i want the `previous GameObject` to be on top and in the order when i `click the button`

```
    public GameObject exampleParent, exampleChild;

    public void gItem(int i)
    {
        Instantiate(exampleChild, exampleParent.transform);
        exampleChild.transform.SetAsFirstSibling();
        exampleChild.gameObject.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = Items[i].gameObject.GetComponent<AddItemC>().textPopup;
    }
```

This is a video of the problem I'm having, `GameObject` should be on `top` and `sorted` from the moment `I click the button`, but `previous` `GameObject` are on the `bottom` :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VKpvuZ5U_o0oVdOmcWIi_A9Qf8LwpCOD/view

And this is the `Grid Layout Group` I'm using:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed to this and it works

```
    public void gItem(int i)
    {
        GameObject obs = Instantiate(exampleChild, exampleParent.transform) as GameObject;
        obs.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<TMP_Text>().text = Items[i].gameObject.GetComponent<AddItemC>().textPopup;().AddItemToPlayer();
    }
```